# How do you populate complex data models when using Linq Query Syntax?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have a pretty basic query which I've written in method syntax, but I need to convert it to query syntax in order to do some sorting/filtering in an effort to avoid the error from [this unresolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764511/how-do-you-avoid-the-ef-core-3-0-restricted-client-evaluation-error-when-tryin). Here's what I have in method syntax:

```
    var Projects = _context.Projects
        .Include(p => p.Bids).ThenInclude(b => b.Vendor)
        .Include(p => p.Category)
        .Include(p => p.Location);
```

This populates a list of Projects for me with all of the information available from the database, and it also populates the linked objects for the Project as well. Here's the class for reference:

```
public class Project : BaseModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
}

public class Bid : BaseModel
{
    public int BidId { get; set; }
    public string BidName { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int? VendorId { get; set; }

    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

In trying to convert this query into 'query syntax' I haven't been able to get it to automatically populate the Location, Category and IList<Bids> properties.

```
    var Projects =
        from prj in _context.Projects
        join bid in _context.Bids on prj.ProjectId equals bid.ProjectId
        join vnd in _context.Vendors on bid.VendorId equals vnd.VendorId
        join cat in _context.Categories on prj.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
        join loc in _context.Vendors on loc.LocationId equals prj.LocationId
        select prj;
```

Using this syntax it will auto-popualte all the base values of the Project class but does not populate any of the linked classes. Is there a way to get these to populate automatically? I played around with a "select New Project{}" statement but that just allows me to set properties of the project directly and I still can't link other objects

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Entity Framework, and a reminder that you should try to tag as specifically as possible.

If Project has many Bids, you want to have a reference that entity framework can use to identify the link between the two entities. For example:

```
public class Project : BaseModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public IList<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
}

public class Bid : BaseModel
{
    public int BidId { get; set; }
    public string BidName { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

The `public Project Project { get; set; }` is what you are missing that EF will use to associate the foreign key.

Other ways are via fluent api or data annotations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: I don't think this actually matters--EF already recognizes the relationship between the two objects in every other context I use them. Like I mentioned, it does popualte the Bids list on the Project class when I use method syntax. The article linked also says you need to have the navigation property on the principal **or** the dependent, so in this case I already had it on the principal. You don't need to have it on both. Relevant part of article: "Navigation property: A property defined on the principal and/ **or** dependent entity that references the related entity."

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data), to load the Related Data, we could use the Include method.

Try to change your code as below:

```
var Projects =
    from prj in _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Bids).ThenInclude(b => b.Vendor).Include(p => p.Category).Include(p => p.Location)
    join bid in _context.Bids on prj.ProjectId equals bid.ProjectId
    join vnd in _context.Vendors on bid.VendorId equals vnd.VendorId
    join cat in _context.Categories on prj.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
    join loc in _context.Vendors on loc.LocationId equals prj.LocationId
    select prj;
```

Or

```
var Projects =
    (from prj in _context.Projects
    join bid in _context.Bids on prj.ProjectId equals bid.ProjectId
    join vnd in _context.Vendors on bid.VendorId equals vnd.VendorId
    join cat in _context.Categories on prj.CategoryId equals cat.CategoryId
    join loc in _context.Vendors on loc.LocationId equals prj.LocationId
    select prj).Include(p => p.Bids).ThenInclude(b => b.Vendor).Include(p => p.Category).Include(p => p.Location)**strong text**;
```

Comment: Isn't this just applying method syntax operations to the query syntax results? This is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place. I did try your suggestion in my app but I end up with the "Client vs. Server evaluation error" that I mentioned/linked in my original post. That's what I was trying to resolve by using query syntax instead of method syntax in the first place, so I don't think this is going to work (unless you have a suggestion on how to fix the issue in the linked post as well)