# How do you avoid Client Evaluation Errors in EF Core when Ordering by a Child property?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When executing the last line of the code below I hit a [client evaluation error](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038). How do I prevent this from happening?

```
IQueryable<Models.Data> dataIQ = _context.Data
        .Include(d => d.Quotes).ThenInclude(q => q.Owner)
        .Include(d => d.Location).ThenInclude(l => l.State)

//This works
dataIQ = dataIQ.OrderBy(d => d.Quotes.FirstOrDefault().QuoteName);

//This also works
dataIQ = dataIQ.OrderBy(d => d.Location.State.StateName);

//This throws the client evaluation error
dataIQ = dataIQ.OrderBy(d => d.Quotes.FirstOrDefault().Owner.OwnerName);
```

For reference, this is what the classes looks like:

```
public class Data
{
    public int DataId { get; set; }
    public string DataName { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public Models.Location Location { get; set; }
    public IList<Models.Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
    public int QuoteId { get; set; }
    public string QuoteName { get; set; }
    public int DataId { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    public Models.State State { get; set; }
}
```

**Error text:**

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '{QUERY TEXT}' could
> not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

This is a continuation of the question asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764511/how-do-you-avoid-the-ef-core-3-0-restricted-client-evaluation-error-when-tryin). The original issue was resolved, so breaking this into its own post

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... one thing that seems to work is switching to the Max function. I think the problem is there's no translation to a SQL command for FirstOrDefault, but there is one for Max. I don't really understand why this works if you're accessing a property of the child and not a sub-child though. Interested to see if anyone has other suggestions for how to address this, or if I'm doing something dumb here

```
//changing to this seems to work
dataIQ = dataIQ.OrderBy(d => d.Quotes.Max(q => q.Owner.OwnerName));
```

I also don't expect this to work if there's a many-to-one relationship, but right now mine is one-to-one. If anyone has suggestions on what to do for many-to-one I'd be interested to hear those as well!